# MULE ESB Server: RAML loading for prolonged time

Tags: api, mule, esb, mule-el, anypoint-studio

I created a mule application and able to run/deploy it on my machine successfully. On running api-console is appearing in Anypoint-studio like this.

[image]

Now when I deployed this application on mule ESB server and try to hit api-console for this application using the following URL                    **"https://mulesoft:ESB****/api/console"**

- Mule is saying RAML loading for prolonged time like the one shown in below image.

I am not able to resolve the issue after working hours on it, If anyone can suggest possible reasons for the occurrence of this issue. It would be a great help to resolve the same.

[image: Mule ESB console keep loading for so long]

Comment: Please check the RAML definition and base URI you have specified.

Comment: both are okay, as the same configuration is working fine on localhost.

Comment: Ok. Can you please check whether some other changes are required for deployment on cloudhub, I mean db settings, environment vars in mule-project.xml etc. Also check the browser console, if you can get some hint there.

Comment: Can you share your RAML here ?

Comment: Qurey is resoved buddy. Thanks for responding.