# RAML loading in cloudhub taking prolonged time

Tags: mule, raml, cloudhub

I created a mule application and able to run/deploy it on my local machine successfully. When I changed the port to Private and deployed to cloudHub, RAML's console is not loading completed.

Same question is also post in below link.

[MULE ESB Server: RAML loading for prolonged time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834268/mule-esb-server-raml-loading-for-prolonged-time)

Could someone please help me out.

[image]

Comment: Did the RAML ever load after a long time? Can you post your RAML here ?

Answer (score 0):

How big is your RAML?  There was bug found where uploads larger than a certain size were timing out and erroring in the backend.

If you watched the network traffic you would see a 504 error being returned to the request.

That particular one got fixed on 27th January so the issue might be solved now?